# Getting error $state not defined in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I am working with Vuejs. I have defined a global variable using the following code in main.js

```
Vue.prototype.$state = Vue.observable({ val: 1 });
```

In another file I want to access this variable inside script so I am using

```
export default {
methods: {
    showup() {
      if ($state.val === 2) $state.val = 1; else $state.val = 2;
    },
  },
```

But I am getting the error as

```
54:11  error  '$state' is not defined  no-undef
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add `this` which refers to the Vue instance :

```js
export default {
methods: {
    showup() {
      if (this.$state.val === 2) this.$state.val = 1; else this.$state.val = 2;
    },
  },
```